# Message ordering is not working properly ,I am beginner I don't know what is happening ,and i am confuse

Tags: flutter, chat, snapshot, stream-builder

here is my code and I'm confused as to why this is happening and I don't really get why the chat is not working in order, when I type in a new message, it doesn't come in the correct place and instead goes between some other messages instead of being the latest one in the list.

[image]

this is my code, Please help me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
final _firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User loggedInUser;
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id='chat_screen';
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController=TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user =await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }





    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: null,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {

                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
          ],
          title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              MessagesStream(),

              Container(
                decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: messageTextController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          messageText=value;
                        },
                        decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                      ),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        messageTextController.clear();
                        _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                          'text':messageText,
                          'sender':loggedInUser.email,




                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Send',
                        style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
}


class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesStream({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
        // ignore: missing_return
        builder:(context,snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
            );
          }
          final messages=snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
          List<MessageBubbol> messageBubbles=[];
          for(var message in messages){
            final data = Map<String, String>.from(message.data());
            final messageText = data['text'];
            final messageSender = data['sender'];
            final currentUser=loggedInUser.email;

            final messageBubble=MessageBubbol(sender:messageSender,text: messageText,isMe:currentUser==messageSender ,);
            messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          }
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              reverse: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 20.0),
              children:messageBubbles,
            ),
          );


        }

    );
  }
}


class MessageBubbol extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubbol({this.sender,this.text,this.isMe});
  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:isMe? CrossAxisAlignment.end:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(sender,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            color: Colors.black54,
          ),),
          Material(
            elevation: 5.0,
            borderRadius:isMe? BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(30.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)):BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
            color: isMe?Colors.lightBlueAccent:Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
               '$text',
                  style:TextStyle(
                    color:isMe? Colors.white:Colors.black54,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a SingleChildScrollView on this Screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
final _firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User loggedInUser;
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id='chat_screen';
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController=TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user =await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }





    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: null,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {

                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
          ],
          title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                MessagesStream(),

                Container(
                  decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: messageTextController,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            messageText=value;
                          },
                          decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                        ),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          messageTextController.clear();
                          _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                            'text':messageText,
                            'sender':loggedInUser.email,




                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Send',
                          style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
}


class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesStream({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
        // ignore: missing_return
        builder:(context,snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
            );
          }
          final messages=snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
          List<MessageBubbol> messageBubbles=[];
          for(var message in messages){
            final data = Map<String, String>.from(message.data());
            final messageText = data['text'];
            final messageSender = data['sender'];
            final currentUser=loggedInUser.email;

            final messageBubble=MessageBubbol(sender:messageSender,text: messageText,isMe:currentUser==messageSender ,);
            messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          }
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              reverse: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 20.0),
              children:messageBubbles,
            ),
          );


        }

    );
  }
}


class MessageBubbol extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubbol({this.sender,this.text,this.isMe});
  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:isMe? CrossAxisAlignment.end:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(sender,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            color: Colors.black54,
          ),),
          Material(
            elevation: 5.0,
            borderRadius:isMe? BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(30.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)):BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
            color: isMe?Colors.lightBlueAccent:Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
               '$text',
                  style:TextStyle(
                    color:isMe? Colors.white:Colors.black54,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hello kietle Now I am getting new errors .

Comment: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.